# Postfix on IspCP cannot send to google apps mail if it is in the same domain

Tags: postfix, g-suite

In my vps setup I have `ispcp omega 1.0.7` installed.

Everything works fine except the fact that postfix cannot send to google apps mail when the domain of google apps is also registered in `ispcp`.

Postfix sends an email to normal addresses `(hotmail, yahoo, gmail etc)`. I use external dns.

There is also a discussion I started in the ispcp forum [here](http://isp-control.net/forum/thread-15892.html)

`.mail.log` file provides these messages:

```
mail for exampledomain.gr loops back to myself".
postfix/bounce: sender non-delivery notification.
postfix/qmgr: removed
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot configure Postfix (or any other mail server) to accept mails for domain `example.com` and then want to send mails to another server pretending to host `example.com`.